# create two new columns by using two existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function  . My data frame is `df' and it has two columns`Ac`and`At`. Both have integer values.

I want to create two new columns `c` and `t`.

- if `Ac ==`At`then`c=1`and`t=1`
- if `Ac > At` then `c=0 and AP=5`
- if `Ac < At` then `c'=1 and AP=3`.

I tried this but neither getting any error nor getting any result.

```py
def my_fun(row): 
    if df.loc[row,"Ac"] == df.loc[row,"At"]:
        df.loc[row,"Ac"] = 1
        df.loc[row,"At"] = 1
    elif df.loc[row,"Ac"] > df.loc[row,"At"]:
        df.loc[row,"Ac"] = 0
        df.loc[row,"At"] = 5
    else:
        df.loc[row,"Ac"] = 1
        df.loc[row,"At"] = 3
```

Comment: post the output you are getting and expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)** instead of loops:

```
cond1 = df['FTHG'].eq(df['FTAG'])
choice1 = [1,1]
cond2 = df['FTHG'].gt(df['FTAG'])
choice2 = [3,0]
cond3 = df['FTHG'].lt(df['FTAG'])
choice3 = [0,3]
df[['HP','AP']]= pd.DataFrame(np.select([cond1[:,None],cond2[:,None],cond3[:,None]],
                                        [choice1,choice2,choice3]))
print(df)
```

---

```
   FTHG  FTAG  HP  AP
0     4     0   3   0
1     1     5   0   3
2     0     3   0   3
3     5     2   3   0
4     7     5   3   0
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
conditions_hp  = [ df['FTHG'] == df['FTHG'],  df['FTHG'] > df['FTHG'],  df['FTHG'] < df['FTHG'] ]
conditions_ap  = [ df['FTHG'] == df['FTHG'],  df['FTHG'] < df['FTHG'],  df['FTHG'] > df['FTHG'] ]
choices     = [ 1, 3, 0 ]
df2['HP'] = np.select(conditions_hp, choices, default=np.nan)
df2['AP'] = np.select(conditions_ap, choices, default=np.nan)
```